# Цикл на Python по ячейке в postgresql

Tags: python

Есть запрос в postgressql, он выводит несколько колонок с информацией, среди которых есть колонка "id", в ней содержатся id в виде чисел. Требуется пройтись циклом по этой колонке, и при встрече id выводить в строку сначала это id, а дальше остальные колонки. 
Написал такой код, но думаю правильнее было бы проверить не на пустоту, а на число и выстроить по возрастанию.

```
result = CreateRecordFormat()
result.AddInt32("id")
result.AddRecordSet("ОстальныеДанныеКiD")
# sql-это сам запрос к базе
res = SqlQuery(sql, id, ПерваяНеделя, ПоследняяНеделя )
CreateRecordSet(result)
for rec in res:
    if rec is not None:
        result["id"].From(res)
```

Comment: "содержатся id в виде чисел" - какой тип? array? И каким драйвером бд пользуетесь? psycopg2?

Comment: `"думаю правильнее было бы проверить не на пустоту, а на число и выстроить по возрастанию"` - зачем делать это на клиенте, когда это можно сделать на стороне БД быстрее и эффективнее?